# Django crashes with Exception Value: no such table: polls_question_page

Tags: django, many-to-many

I get an error when I try to add a many to many fields :

```
page = models.ManyToManyField(Page)
```

I get this error : `no such table: polls_question_page`

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Question(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    page = models.ManyToManyField(Page)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.label

class Reply(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Personne)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now(),blank=True, verbose_name="Date de création") 

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.answer)
```

Traceback:

```
File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  323.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (no such table: polls_question_page) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  541.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  244.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in change_view
  1438.         return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/contextlib.py" in inner
  30.                 return func(*args, **kwds)

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1395.                 form = ModelForm(instance=obj)

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in __init__
  282.             object_data = model_to_dict(instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in model_to_dict
  105.                     data[f.name] = list(qs.values_list('pk', flat=True))

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  258.         self._fetch_all()

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1074.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  158.         for row in compiler.results_iter():

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in results_iter
  802.             results = self.execute_sql(MULTI)

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  848.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  95.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  323.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/polls/question/4/change/
Exception Value: no such table: polls_question_page
```

Why can not I add my fields "page" in my class Question? Why I do not manage to access my admin
When I remove this fields are any worries to see the class question in my admin panel but I would add a ManyToMany key on page ...

**I join another to do?**

EDIT :

when i run : `python manage.py makemigrations`

```
/home/nicolas/webtrial/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/grappelli/urls.py:21: RemovedInDjango110Warning: django.conf.urls.patterns() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10. Update your urlpatterns to be a list of django.conf.urls.url() instances instead.
  url(r'^switch/user/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', switch_user, name="grp_switch_user"),

System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
polls.Message.pub_date: (fields.W161) Fixed default value provided.
    HINT: It seems you set a fixed date / time / datetime value as default for this field. This may not be what you want. If you want to have the current date as default, use `django.utils.timezone.now`
polls.Reply.creationDate: (fields.W161) Fixed default value provided.
    HINT: It seems you set a fixed date / time / datetime value as default for this field. This may not be what you want. If you want to have the current date as default, use `django.utils.timezone.now`
No changes detected
```

Comment: did you run makemigrations after adding and ten migrate?

Comment: i have edit when i run makemigrations

Comment: And i have again the same error :3

Comment: try adding blank=True in your `Message.pub_date` field and remove blank=True from `Reply.creationDate`, please do the changes and run again to see if it works.

Comment: @ChitrankDixit I did what you said but i have again the same error I don't understand :/

Comment: You have to run both `makemigrations` and then `migrate`. If it still doesn't work, you can flush the database and run `migrate` from a clean slate.

Comment: You should read the warnings from the `makemigrations` output and consider fixing them, even though they aren't relevant for this specific problem.

Comment: i have already flush my database and run migrate but it does not work yet

Comment: `manage.py migrate polls zero && manage.py migrate` See my answer for what this does.

Comment: You can also delete or clear you database manually, but that depends on which database you are using. Another option is the command `reset_db` from the package django-extensions, which also contains many other useful tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that the django model and your database are not in sync, and you have to make and run migrations.

```
Exception Value: no such table: polls_question_page
```

Run these management commands:

```
manage.py makemigrations && manage.py migrate
```

**If that doesn't work you will have to repair the database**

Get a list of which migrations is supposed to have been applied

```
manage.py showmigrations
```

Read through the source of the migrations for the app "polls" and find out which that hasn't been applied. Then you can roll back to before the migration. Let's say that you want to roll back to a migration called "0004_something_something"

```
manage.py migrate polls 0004
```

If there's an error you can [fake it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate--fake).

```
manage.py migrate polls 0004 --fake
```

Then you rerun the migrations.

```
manage.py migrate polls
```

Hopefully this will fix everything. If not, you might want to just start over with an empty database.

The easiest way to reset your database completely is probably the command `reset_db` from the package [django-extensions](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/).

> **reset_db** - Resets a database (currently sqlite3, mysql, postgres).
>   Uses “DROP DATABASE” and “CREATE DATABASE”.

Comment: Lid                                            `(dev)nicolas@nicolas-Latitude-E6510:~/webtrial/dev/webtrial$ python manage.py migrate polls 0004 --fake
CommandError: App 'polls' does not have migrations.`

Comment: I don't know if it's normal or not

Comment: That explains your problem. Run these commands `manage.py makemigrations poll && manage.py migrate`

Comment: Lid `(dev)nicolas@nicolas-Latitude-E6510:~/webtrial/dev/webtrial$ python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate
No changes detected
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: contenttypes, admin, sessions, auth
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.`

Comment: You forgot to add "poll" : `manage.py makemigrations poll` 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#adding-migrations-to-apps

Comment: `python manage.py makemigrations polls
Migrations for 'polls':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Campus
    - Create model Champs
    - Create model Cursus
    - Create model Document
    - Create model Faculte
    - Create model Fonction
    - Create model Message
    - Create model Page
    - Create model Personne
    - Create model Question
    - Create model Reply
    - Create model Employe
    - Create model Etudiant
    - Add field user to reply
    - Add field amis to personne
    - Add field faculte to personne
    - Add field auteur to message`

Comment: It's okay but i have again the same error but i have now a result when i run makemigrations polls

Comment: Did you run `migrate` after you made migrations? Have you read the documentation? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/